# best way to get available dimensions for svg in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

In this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qiluxi/2/edit?html,js,output) I am getting the available width like this:

```
  getDimensions() {
    const minWidth = window.innerWidth;

    const margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 50,
      left: 50,
      bottom: 50
    };

    const width = minWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

    const height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    return {
      margin,
      width,
      height
    };
  }
```

I then use this to set the width of my `svg element`:

```
const el = this.refs.sine;

const dimensions = this.getDimensions();

const xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 20])
        .range([0, dimensions.width]);

const yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 20])
        .range([dimensions.height, 0]);

const svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
  .attr("width", dimensions.width)
  .attr("height", dimensions.height);
```

It grabs the available width and height in desktop but in mobile it does not.

Can anyone suggest a better way of having a `responsive layout` for `svg`?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the parent `width/height` of the chart id in this case `el` or you can directly calculate the width/height of `body`. Below is the example to do so using `jquery`:

```
  var containerWidth = $("#el").parent().width();
  var containerheight = $("#el").parent().height();
  var margin = {top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 40, left:40},
      width = containerWidth- margin.left - margin.right,
      height = containerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```